# Linear diophantine inequality maximum

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linear-diophantine-equations

For an irrational $\xi$ and given bound $x$, find integer $a, b \ge 0$ maximizing $y = a + b\xi$ subject to $y \le x$.

$\xi$ is a square root of an integer, but I guess it doesn't matter. It's actually an ILP, but I can't see how to use this fact.